# What is a scoped proxy in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, singleton, dynamic-proxy

As we know Spring uses proxies to add functionality (`@Transactional` and `@Scheduled` for example). There are two options - using a JDK dynamic proxy (the class has to implement non-empty interfaces), or generating a child class using the CGLIB code generator. I always thought that proxyMode allows me to choose between a JDK dynamic proxy and CGLIB.

But I was able to create an example which shows that my assumption is wrong:

### Case 1:

**Singleton:**

```
@Service
public class MyBeanA {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanB myBeanB;

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println(myBeanB.getCounter());
    }

    public MyBeanB getMyBeanB() {
        return myBeanB;
    }
}
```

**Prototype:**

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class MyBeanB {
    private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(0);

    private Long index;

    public MyBeanB() {
        index = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
        System.out.println("constructor invocation:" + index);
    }

    @Transactional // just to force Spring to create a proxy
    public long getCounter() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

**Main:**

```
MyBeanA beanA = context.getBean(MyBeanA.class);
beanA.foo();
beanA.foo();
MyBeanB myBeanB = beanA.getMyBeanB();
System.out.println("counter: " + myBeanB.getCounter() + ", class=" + myBeanB.getClass());
```

**Output:**

```
constructor invocation:0
0
0
counter: 0, class=class test.pack.MyBeanB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f3d648e
```

Here we can see two things:

1. `MyBeanB` was instantiated only **once**.
2. To add the `@Transactional` functionality for `MyBeanB`, Spring used CGLIB.

### Case 2:

Let me correct the `MyBeanB` definition:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyBeanB {
```

In this case the output is:

```
constructor invocation:0
0
constructor invocation:1
1
constructor invocation:2
counter: 2, class=class test.pack.MyBeanB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b06d71f2
```

Here we can see two things:

1. `MyBeanB` was instantiated **3** times.
2. To add the `@Transactional` functionality for `MyBeanB`, Spring used CGLIB.

Could you explain what is going on? How does proxy mode really work?

### P.S.

I've read the documentation:

```
/**
 * Specifies whether a component should be configured as a scoped proxy
 * and if so, whether the proxy should be interface-based or subclass-based.
 * <p>Defaults to {@link ScopedProxyMode#DEFAULT}, which typically indicates
 * that no scoped proxy should be created unless a different default
 * has been configured at the component-scan instruction level.
 * <p>Analogous to {@code <aop:scoped-proxy/>} support in Spring XML.
 * @see ScopedProxyMode
 */
```

but it is not clear for me.

### Update

### Case 3:

I investigated one more case, in which I extracted the interface from `MyBeanB`:

```
public interface MyBeanBInterface {
    long getCounter();
}



@Service
public class MyBeanA {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanBInterface myBeanB;


@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MyBeanB implements MyBeanBInterface {
```

and in this case the output is:

```
constructor invocation:0
0
constructor invocation:1
1
constructor invocation:2
counter: 2, class=class com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92
```

Here we can see two things:

1. `MyBeanB` was instantiated **3** times.
2. To add the `@Transactional` functionality for `MyBeanB`, Spring used a JDK dynamic proxy.

Comment: Please show us your transactional configuration.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't have any special configuration

Comment: I don't know about scoped beans or whatever other kind of enterprise framework magic contained in Spring or JEE. @SotiriosDelimanolis wrote a wonderful answer about that stuff, I want to comment only on JDK vs. CGLIB proxies: In cases 1 and 2 your `MyBeanB` class does not extend any interfaces, so it is not surprising that your console log shows CGLIB proxy instances. In case 3 you introduce and implement an interface, consequently you get a JDK proxy. You even describe this in your introductory text.

Comment: So for non-interface types you really have no choice, they have to be CGLIB proxies because JDK proxies only work for interface types. You can however enforce CGLIB proxies even for interface types when using Spring AOP. This is configured via `<aop:config proxy-target-class="true">` or `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`, respectively.

Comment: @kriegaex Do you want to say that Aspectj uses CGlib for proxy generation?

Comment: I was talking about Spring AOP. AspectJ does not use any proxies at all.

Comment: @kriegaex could you elaborate what you mean ? AOP helps us to insert some piece of code before/after/instead.... some method/... Spring uses it for Transactional, Scheduled, Async...annotations. But bean with inserted AOP is a Proxy

Comment: Please read the [Spring AOP manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop), especially chapter [understanding AOP proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies). Spring AOP supports a subset of AspectJ's [pointcut designators](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-pointcuts-designators). If you need more power, use [AspectJ via LTW](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-using-aspectj).

Comment: Adding a link to the documentation: [ScopedProxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/javadoc-api/org/springframework/config/java/annotation/aop/ScopedProxy.html)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The proxy generated for `@Transactional` behavior serves a different purpose than the scoped proxies.

The `@Transactional` proxy is one that wraps the specific bean to add session management behavior. All method invocations will perform the transaction management before and after delegating to the actual bean.

If you illustrate it, it would look like

```
main -> getCounter -> (cglib-proxy -> MyBeanB)
```

For our purposes, you can essentially ignore its behavior (remove `@Transactional` and you should see the same behavior, except you won't have the cglib proxy).

The [`@Scope` proxy](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) behaves differently. The documentation states:

> [...] you need to inject a proxy object that exposes the same
>   public interface as the scoped object **but that can also retrieve the
>   real target object from the relevant scope** (such as an HTTP request)
>   and delegate method calls onto the real object.

What Spring is really doing is creating a singleton bean definition for a type of factory representing the proxy. The corresponding proxy object, however, queries the context for the actual bean for every invocation.

If you illustrate it, it would look like

```
main -> getCounter -> (cglib-scoped-proxy -> context/bean-factory -> new MyBeanB)
```

Since `MyBeanB` is a prototype bean, the context will always return a new instance.

For the purposes of this answer, assume you retrieved the `MyBeanB` directly with

```
MyBeanB beanB = context.getBean(MyBeanB.class);
```

which is essentially what Spring does to satisfy an `@Autowired` injection target.

---

In your first example,

```java
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class MyBeanB {
```

You declare a [prototype bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype) definition (through the annotations). [`@Scope`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html) has a [`proxyMode`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.html#proxyMode--) element which

> Specifies whether a component should be configured as a scoped proxy
>   and if so, whether the proxy should be interface-based or
>   subclass-based.
>
> **Defaults to `ScopedProxyMode.DEFAULT`, which typically indicates that no
>   scoped proxy should be created** unless a different default has been
>   configured at the component-scan instruction level.

So Spring is not creating a scoped proxy for the resulting bean. You retrieve that bean with

```
MyBeanB beanB = context.getBean(MyBeanB.class);
```

You now have a reference to a new `MyBeanB` object created by Spring. This is like any other Java object, method invocations will go directly to the referenced instance.

If you used `getBean(MyBeanB.class)` again, Spring would return a new instance, since the bean definition is for a [prototype bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype). You're not doing that, so all your method invocations go to the same object.

---

In your second example,

```java
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyBeanB {
```

you declare a scoped proxy that is implemented through cglib. When requesting a bean of this type from Spring with

```java
MyBeanB beanB = context.getBean(MyBeanB.class);
```

Spring knows that `MyBeanB` is a scoped proxy and therefore returns a proxy object that satisfies the API of `MyBeanB` (ie. implements all its public methods) that internally knows how to retrieve an actual bean of type `MyBeanB` for each method invocation.

Try running

```java
System.out.println("singleton?: " + (context.getBean(MyBeanB.class) == context.getBean(MyBeanB.class)));
```

This will return `true` hinting to the fact that Spring is returning a singleton proxy object (not a prototype bean).

On a method invocation, inside the proxy implementation, Spring will use a special `getBean` version that knows how to distinguish between the proxy definition and the actual `MyBeanB` bean definition. That'll return a new `MyBeanB` instance (since it's a prototype) and Spring will delegate the method invocation to it through reflection (classic `Method.invoke`).

---

Your third example is essentially the same as your second.