# Why don't I experience any exception when I lookup bean wrapped by JDK dynamic proxy by class(instead of interface)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, dynamic-proxy

Lets consider following bean:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class MyBeanB implements MyBeanBInterface {
    private static final AtomicLong COUNTER = new AtomicLong(0);

    private Long index;

    public MyBeanB() {
        index = COUNTER.getAndIncrement();
        System.out.println("constructor invocation:" + index);
    }

    @Transactional 
    @Override
    public long getCounter() {
        return index;
    }
}
```

and consider 2 different usages:

### USAGE 1:

```
@Service
public class MyBeanA {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanB myBeanB;   
    ....
}
```

At this case application can't be started and prints:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The bean 'myBeanB' could not be injected as a 'my.pack.MyBeanB' because it is a JDK dynamic proxy that implements:
    my.pack.MyBeanBInterface


Action:

Consider injecting the bean as one of its interfaces or forcing the use of CGLib-based proxies by setting proxyTargetClass=true on @EnableAsync and/or @EnableCaching.
```

I expected to see it because I asked spring to create JDK dynamic proxy for bean `MyBeanB` and that proxy is not a subtype of MyBeanB. We can easily fix it like this:

```
@Service
public class MyBeanA {
    @Autowired
    private MyBeanBInterface myBeanB;   
    ....
}
```

### USAGE 2:

```
MyBeanB beanB = context.getBean(MyBeanB.class);
System.out.println(beanB.getCounter());
```

Surprisingly for me it works wihtout any Runtime Exceptions but I expected to see `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` at this case because int case 1 application can't start

Thanks for guy from comments - I checked the class of `beanB` and it is `my.pack.MyBeanB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1346261` so Spring used CGLIB to create proxy but it contradicts the bean definition(`@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES`) and looks like a bug.
)

Could you explain why it is working for case 2 not working for case 1 ?

Comment: what kind of object do you actually get back? the context delegates to a BeanFactory, and that one jumps through a lot of hoops to find candidates. i believe this should return the actual instance, not a proxy - check the docs on AppCtx.getBean() ... i don't think it is even claiming to do the same as @Autowire does ....

Comment: @rmalchow, I checked class and it is **my.pack.MyBeanB$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1346261**

Comment: @rmalchow, I expect that it should very similar to Autowire behaviour. If not - please explain

Comment: i wasnt all that sure ... i was just wondering. how exactly do you obtain your "context" object?

Comment: the fact that one way refuses to do cglib, while the other one happily does it is certainly ... surprising?

Comment: It is surprising for me to. It is because I've created the topic

Comment: apart from the fact that it returns a cglib proxy of the concrete class instead of the JDK proxy of the interfaces ... does it behave correctly? i.e. return a fresh one on every call?

Comment: ... oh ... wait a minute ... does it actually DO return a proxy of the concrete class? could you try to do some introspection on the proxy you get? does proxy the class, or does it proxy its interfaces?

Comment: @rmalchow,       **System.out.println(context.getBean(MyBeanB.class) == context.getBean(MyBeanB.class));** prints **false** so it behaves correctly

Comment: @rmalchow, actually I don't know how to introspect proxy to understand what you asked me

Comment: ok, i played around with it myself ... i would be confident in reporting this as a bug now. while it DOES behave somewhat correctly, it should honor the proxy mode. and it clearly doesnt.

Comment: I think we need to ask Juergen Hoeller to prove it somehow

Answer (score 5):

As I explained to you in my comments to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58170627/1082681), Spring AOP can use both CGLIB and JDK proxies depending on the situation. The default are JDK proxies for classes implementing interfaces, but you can enforce CGLIB usage for them too. For classes not implementing interfaces only CGLIB remains because JDK proxies can only create dynamic proxies based on interfaces.

So looking at your case 1, you explicitly say you want interface proxies, i.e. JDK proxies:

```java
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
```

But `MyBeanA` does not implement any interfaces. Consequently you get the error message you see in this case.

In case 2 however you use `ApplicationContext.getBean(..)` in order to create a proxy. Here you are relying on Spring to determine which proxy type to choose, you are not trying to enforce anything. Thus, proxying via CGLIB succeeds.

No surprises here.

If you want to avoid the error message in case 1, maybe you ought to use `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.

---

**Update:** Sorry, I was irritated by your similar and nondescript class names `MyBeanA` and `MyBeanB`. It would make sense to use more descriptive, clean-code-like class names next time, ideally ones describing the roles ob the classes in your scenario like `MyService`, `MyInterface`, `MyScopedBean`.

Anyway, I read your question and the error message again. The error message says that according to your annotation an interface-based proxy is being generated but you are trying to inject it into a class type. You can fix that by declaring it like this:

```java
@Autowired
private MyBeanBInterface myBeanB;
```

In case/usage 2 you are again explicitly declaring a class and not an interface type for your bean. So as I said, Spring tries to satisfy your requirement by the only way possible, i.e. creating a CGLIB proxy for the class. You can fix this by declaring an interface type and you will get the expected JDK proxy:

```java
MyBeanBInterface myBeanBInterface = appContext.getBean(MyBeanBInterface.class);
System.out.println(myBeanBInterface.getCounter());
System.out.println(myBeanBInterface.getClass());
```

---

**Update 2:** Something I think you still do not understand according to your comments is this basic fact of OOP: If you have

- class `Base` and class `Sub extends Base` or
- interface `Base` and class `Sub implements Base`

you can declare `Base b = new Sub()` but of course not `Sub s = new Base()` because a `Sub` is also a `Base`, but not every `Base` is a `Sub`. For example, if you also have `OtherSub extends Base`, when trying to assign a `Base` object to a `Sub` variable it could be an `OtherSub` instance. This is why this does dot even compile without using `Sub s = (Sub) myBaseObject`.

So far, so good. Now look at your code again:

In **usage 1** you have `@Autowired private MyBeanB myBeanB;` but configured `MyBeanB` to produce a JDK proxy, i.e. a new proxy class with parent class `Proxy` directly implementing `MyBeanBInterface` will be created. I.e. you have two different classes, both directly implementing the same interface. Those classes are assignment-incompatible to each other for the reason I explained above. With regard to the interface we have the class hierarchy

```
MyBeanBInterface
  MyBeanB
  MyBeanB_JDKProxy
```

Thus you cannot inject `MyBeanB_JDKProxy` into a `MyBeanB` field because a proxy object is not an instance of `MyBeanB`. Don't you understand? The problem sits in front of the computer, there is no mysterious Spring bug. You configured it to fail.

This is why I told you to change the code to `@Autowired private MyBeanBInterface myBeanB;` because then of course it works because the proxy implements the interface and everything is fine. I also told you that alternatively you can keep `@Autowired private MyBeanB myBeanB;` if you use `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` for your scope declaration.

In **usage 2** the problem is the same: You are saying `getBean(ClassB.class)`, i.e. you are explicitly instructing Spring to create a proxy for that class. But for a class you cannot create a JDK proxy, only a CGLIB proxy, which is what Spring does. Again, I gave you the solution by instructing you to use `getBean(MyBeanBInterface.class)` instead. Then you get the expected JDK proxy.

Spring is smart enough to both

- make the JDK proxy in usage 1 find the scoped service bean `MyClassB` and delegate method calls to it (note: delegation, not inheritance!) and
- make the CGLIB proxy extend `MyClassB` (note: inheritance here, no delegation necessary).

Comment: **Here you are relying on Spring to determine which proxy type to choose** - why do you think so ?  class marked with annotation **@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)** so Spring knows about it. In remain part of your post I absolutely agree with you.

Comment: I've read you answer as carefully as I able. I didn't get what I am mxing up. From my view in all cases(usages, call it according your preferences) I rely on Spring for bean creation. I even can proove it easily - if I replace @Scope(value = "prototype") with @Scope(value = "singleton") spring will always return the same bean for any case/usage.

Comment: Actually you were mixing up my remarks but I was mixing up all too similar bean class names. My bad. I have updated my answer just now, please see if it helps.

Comment: I got your opinion. We have different opinions about expected result of **USAGE 2**. You think that it is Ok because Spring tries to do best to return bean according my requirements(**context.getBean(MyBeanB.class)**) but I consider it is as a bug because **MyBeanB** marked with **@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)**

Comment: thank you for you opinion. I am sorry that I was not able to explain my point of view for you. But you know several persons has the same opinion as me(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221152/why-dont-i-experience-any-exception-when-i-lookup-bean-wrapped-by-jdk-dynamic-p/58228900?noredirect=1#comment102820595_58221152 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170627/what-is-a-scoped-proxy-in-spring#comment102795974_58207312)

Comment: If you think it is a bug (I still disagree), go open a ticket for Spring and link to it here. Good luck.

Comment: **Update 2:** more detailed explanation added. I gave it another try to explain to you and convince you that your expectations are wrong with regard to Spring and Java in general work. Please read and reconsider.

Comment: Actually your explanation is correct and duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762454/2674303 which I've read. But my point that if class marked with **@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)** Spring should complain when I do lookup by class(instead of interface)

Comment: Let allow community to decide - I opened bounty. For me, personaly, your arguments do not look convincing. But I  admit that I'm wrong

Comment: You opened your bounty, nobody else had a better answer (or any answer other than mine at all even after 4 months). I would appreciate you to finally accept + upvote my correct and detailed answer.